# How does Orange calculate confidence intervals in its Distribution widget?

Tags: orange

When using the Distribution widget of Orange on a binary classification dataset there's the option of showing confidence intervals for the probabilities of a given class label for all feature values, see: [Distribution Widget Doc](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/widgets/rst/visualize/distributions.html#distributions)

How are these intervals calculated? I've tried searching [the github repo](https://github.com/biolab/orange) using keywords: 'distribution', 'confidence interval'. But have only found the code for the widget UI and no pointers to where the actual stats are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

It's done in the calcHistogramAndProbGraph method of OWDistributions.py ([code](https://github.com/biolab/orange/blob/8f964e2005b75d80c9ecbddd1740a7d6c7954e22/Orange/OrangeWidgets/Visualize/OWDistributions.py)), which is the code for the distributions widget.

For discrete features it's simply the observed ratio. For continuous features it calls out to C++ code that (I assume) discretizes the feature and estimates the probability in a similar fashion.